# WPF MVVM Dynamic ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
<Custom:DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemsList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Custom:DataGrid.ContextMenu>

public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuItemsList
        {
            get
            {
                     ObservableCollection<MenuItemClass> list = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemClass>();
                if (SelectedInspection != null)
                {
                    switch (SelectedInspection.state.s_serverid)
                    {
                        case 1:
                        case 2:
                            list.Add(medit);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            list.Add(msync);
                            list.Add(mview);
                            list.Add(mnewdoc);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            list.Add(mview);
                            list.Add(mdelete);
                            break;
                    }
                }
               return list;
            }
            set
            {
                OnPropertyChanged("MenuItemsList");
            }
        }
```

ContextMenu (CM) is in UserControl 1 (UC1).
Window have 2 usercontrols and main menu to select this controls.

Select UC1 
Use CM - OK 
Select UC2 
Select UC1 
Use CM - OK

**But** 
Select UC1
 Use CM - OK 
Select UC1 
Use CM - not update CM Items

I think I should update the view of UC1 when create new viewmodel of UC1, but how?
Or may be I should rewrite ContextMenu realisation?

Comment: Just a small information: You should not create ObservableCollections with the type of an UIElement. You should use a object here which holds your business-logic.

Comment: @Tomtom do you mean "own classes" for example?

Comment: yes, exactly that's what I mean

Comment: @Tomtom I have changed, but it does not work too =(

Comment: The classes don't have any relation to your problem. This was just an information for using MVVM. I don't get your problem: If you select UC1 then the context-menu-items are ok. Then you select UC1 again and your context-menu-items-collection is not updated. This is correct, because the collection doesn't change. You still have the same UserControl

Comment: @Tomtom imagine that in Get I generate new collection =) But it does not work too

Comment: Is the code above for your the MenuItemsList-Property your real code?

Answer (score 0):

Okay.

First of all:

The code in the getter should be moved into the model.

And now to your problem:

Your setter should look like

```
set
{
   this.MenuItemsList = value;
   OnPropertyChanged("MenuItemsList");
}
```

Comment: In get shoul be only return list = GetMenu(); ?

Comment: Normally in MVVM you have a backend-field for each property. The property then only sets/gets the backend-field and fires OnPropertyChanged in the setter

Comment: I know it, but if I write it on set, then when set will be called?